# SQL Live Beginner

Tags: sql, oracle

A student learning about SQL Live for the first time - I am attempting to create tables, but the problem is that I receive this error code: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. Unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp 
(
    Empno INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Ename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DNO INT,
    BirthDate DATE,
    Sal DECIMAL(10,2) CHECK (Sal BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Dept_Emp FOREIGN KEY (DNO) REFERENCES Dept(Deptno)
);

CREATE TABLE Dept 
(
    Deptno INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Dname VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Mgr INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Emp_Dept FOREIGN KEY (Mgr) REFERENCES Emp(Empno)
);
```

These were my instructions:

Using SQL Live, create two tables:

- Emp (Empno, Ename, DNO, BirthDate, Sal)
- Dept (Deptno, Dname, Mgr)

Select by yourself the appropriate data type for each column.

For `Emp` table add the following constraints: Empno is the PK, Ename not null, DNO is FK references Dept(Deptno), Sal should be between 1000 and 10000

For `Dept` table add the following Constraint: Deptno is PK, Dname is unique, Mgr is FK reference Emp(Empno).

Comment: In your case better to add foreign keys via `ALTER TABLE`

Comment: You are trying to create a foreign key that does not exist (the reference is not found), like @VasylMoskalov has stated you will need to use the `ALTER` keyword to update the constraint once the tables have been created, this is the problem with one-to-one relationships...

Comment: Additionally you need to specify this constraint as initially deferred, because you will not be able to insert a row with `mgr` filled in `dept` or `dno` filled in `emp`: you should have a manager assigned to the department but `emp` row for this manager should also exist and reference this department you are trying to insert. Possibly it would be better to have a separate assignment table (which is a general approach in HCM solutions)

Comment: What is "SQL Live" ? Are you talking about "Oracle Live SQL" ? The answer is in the other comments. You can only create a foreign key to an existing table - so your first create table statement cannot contain the foreign key clause. Create Emp without foreign key, then create dept (with fk), then alter table emp to add foreign key to dept.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you are trying to create interdependent foreign keys and no matter whichever order you try they will give error because 1 foreign key will not be present before another.

To overcome this problem. Try creating 1 table without foreign key. Then create another table and then add the foreign in first table through `ALTER TABLE` command -

```
CREATE TABLE Emp 
(
    Empno INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Ename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DNO INT,
    BirthDate DATE,
    Sal DECIMAL(10,2) CHECK (Sal BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000)
);

CREATE TABLE Dept 
(
    Deptno INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Dname VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Mgr INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Emp_Dept FOREIGN KEY (Mgr) REFERENCES Emp(Empno)
);

ALTER TABLE Emp ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Dept_Emp FOREIGN KEY (DNO) REFERENCES Dept(Deptno);
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/aCF3tVf8)